Cytoscape.js - Making Nodes present within container even if the node count and size are increasing dynamically
I am working to draw a flow chart with Cytoscape.js framework. I have n-number of nodes and edges. One node can have multiple children. The output should appear like a flow chart with connections.
Initially, I kept my container size as static. Based on node count increase, i am increasing the height of the container. And currently, few of my nodes are crossing the border of the container. So need a solution to avoid that problem. I am following breadthfirst layout.


var elements = [{data:{id:"A",label:"A",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"B",label:"B",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"C",label:"C",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"D",label:"D",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"E",label:"E",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"F",label:"F",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"G",label:"G",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"H",label:"H",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"I",label:"I",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"J",label:"J",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"K",label:"K",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{id:"L",label:"L",shape:"diamond"}},{data:{source:"A",target:"B"}},{data:{source:"B",target:"C"}},{data:{source:"C",target:"D"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"E"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"F"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"G"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"H"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"I"}},{data:{source:"G",target:"J"}},{data:{source:"J",target:"K"}},{data:{source:"D",target:"L"}}];

var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  elements: elements,
  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      style: {
        "label": "data(label)",
        "shape": "data(shape)",
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        "font-size": "25px",
        "text-wrap": "wrap",
        "color": "#000",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "60px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      style: {
        'width': "2px",
        "height": "50px",
        'line-color': '#000',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve',
        'target-arrow-color': '#000',
        "curve-style": "bezier"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    padding: 10,
    spacingFactor: 1.5,
    fit: true,
    avoidOverlap: true,
  },
  zoomingEnabled: false
});

function adjustContainerHeight() {
  var maxY = 0;
  var minY = Infinity;

  cy.nodes().forEach(function(node) {
    var nodePosition = node.position();
    var nodeY = nodePosition.y;
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, nodeY);
    minY = Math.min(minY, nodeY);
  });

  var newHeight = maxY - minY + 35;
  document.getElementById("cy").style.height = newHeight + "px";
};

adjustContainerHeight();
cy.layout({
  name: 'breadthfirst',
  directed: true,
  padding: 10,
  spacingFactor: 1.5,
  fit: true,
  avoidOverlap: true,
  orientation: "vertical"
}).run();

cy.on("add", "node", function() {
  cy.layout({
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    padding: 10,
    spacingFactor: 1.5,
    fit: true,
    avoidOverlap: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  }).run();
  adjustContainerHeight();
});
#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<div id="cy"></div>




I think you add all your elements at the beginning while creating the cytoscape instance. I don't see any code where you add new nodes so cy.on("add".. is not called.

With the existing data, few of the nodes are crossing the border. And when i add new node, the existing one is getting pushed into the border and new one is getting placed outside of the border. This is what i observed. @HasanBalcı
